# TypeScript: How to let a child class know a type of class in which it was instantiated?

Tags: typescript

Well, the title might be misleading. I am also not sure if I even going in the right direction, but what I am trying to achieve is the following.

I have a `ChildClass` and `BasicClass` that I need to use as is most of the time.

```
type BasicClassParams = {
    data: string
    children: string[]
}

class BasicClass {
    data: string
    children: ChildClass[]

    constructor(params: BasicClassParams) {
        this.data = params.data
        this.children = this.createChildren(params.children)
    }

    createChildren(children) {
        return children.map(child => new ChildClass(child, this))
    }
}

class ChildClass<T extends BasicClass = BasicClass> {
    data: string
    parent: T

    constructor(data: string, parent: T) {
        this.data = data
        this.parent = parent
    }
}
```

At some point occured that I need to extend `BasicClass` to have some additional fields:

```
type ExtendedClassParams = BasicClassParams & {
    additional_data: string
}

class ExtendedClass extends BasicClass {
    additional_data: string

    constructor(params: ExtendedClassParams) {
        super(params)
        this.additional_data = params.additional_data
    }
}
```

And I have a `SuperClass` that is going to work with the extended version:

```
class SuperClass {
    class: ExtendedClass

    constructor(data: string, children: string[]) {
        this.class = new ExtendedClass({ data, children, additional_data: 'Hello' })
    }
}
```

And the problem here is:

```
const super_class = new SuperClass('Hello', ['123'])

super_class.class.children[0].parent.additional_data // Property 'additional_data' does not exist on type 'BasicClass'.
```

So, is there a way to let children know in which class they were created to get the right typing (without type assetion preferably)?

P.S. Please note that the example code above is entirely synthetic and serves as a minimal reproduction of the issue. It does not offer a comprehensive representation of my code structure, which is somewhat more intricate

Comment: Just declare `children: ChildClass<ExtendedClass>[]` in the `ExtendedClass`? You can also use `children: ChildClass<this>[]` right away, instead of having the generic parameter default to `BasicClass`.

Comment: I would recommend to remove `T extends BasicClass = BasicClass` and use only `T extends BasicClass` to declare type parameters, to get better error messages while you are working on the code (and do not yet need to deal with conciseness or backwards compatibility).